# Does R have non-linear optimization package(s) that scale well on cluster?

Tags: optimization, r

This is a copy of my [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821179/does-r-have-non-linear-optimization-packages-that-scale-well-on-cluster) that was closed as off-topic because it was asking for a software recommendation. I only hope it wouldn't get closed at Software Recommendations SE for being a copy of the above SO post...

I'm looking for an R optimization package that is:

1. Capable of non-linear global optimization with linear constraints for a non-linear function of 20-ish variables.
2. Scalable to a cluster.

I know from answers to similar questions that non-linear optimization packages for R are available; I don't know which ones are scalable.

Could you recommend one?